# Border for tkinter Label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a calendar that would look much nicer if it had some borders for its Labels!

I have seen you can do this for other widgets such as Button, Entry and Text.

Minimal code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

L1 = Label(root, text="This")
L2 = Label(root, text="That")

L1.pack()
L2.pack()
```

I have tried setting

```
highlightthickness=4
highlightcolor="black"
highlightbackground="black"
borderwidth=4
```

inside the widget, but still the same result.

[image: example pic tkinter]

Is this even possible to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

If you want a border, the option is `borderwidth`. You can also choose the relief of the border: `"flat"`, `"raised"`, `"sunken"`, `"ridge"`, `"solid"`, and `"groove"`.

For example:

```
l1 = Label(root, text="This", borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
```

---

Note: `"ridge"` and `"groove"` require at least two pixels of width to render properly

[image: examples of tkinter borders]

Comment: Very nice picture. Tkinter needs someone like you writing the manual :)

Comment: @bryan-oakley would you happen to know if there is there a way to change to color of the solid border in your example?  Looking for something quick with an existing tk.Label rather than switching over to styles.

Comment: @Brown You can change the background of the label. It worked for me. Or you can use the bordercolor parameter like the second answer says.

Comment: @10Rep: there is no `bordercolor` parameter.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yep, you're correct. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

@Pax Vobiscum - A way to do this is to take a widget and throw a frame with a color behind the widget. Tkinter for all its usefulness can be a bit primitive in its feature set. A bordercolor option would be logical for any widget toolkit, but there does not seem to be one.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
topframe = Frame(root, width = 300, height = 900)
topframe.pack()

frame = Frame(root, width = 202, height = 32, highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, bd=0)
l = Entry(frame, borderwidth=0, relief="flat", highlightcolor="white")
l.place(width=200, height=30)
frame.pack
frame.pack()
frame.place(x = 50, y = 30)
```

An example using this method, could be to create a table:

```
from Tkinter import *

def EntryBox(root_frame, w, h):
    boxframe = Frame(root_frame, width = w+2, height= h+2, highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, bd=0)
    l = Entry(boxframe, borderwidth=0, relief="flat", highlightcolor="white")
    l.place(width=w, height=h)
    l.pack()
    boxframe.pack()
    return boxframe

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width = 1800, height = 1800)
frame.pack()

labels = []

for i in range(16):
    for j in range(16):
        box = EntryBox(frame, 40, 30)
        box.place(x = 50 + i*100, y = 30 + j*30 , width = 100, height = 30)
        labels.append(box)
```