# How to make border for my table using python tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Apparently, my application can display the excel file but it is a bit messy without border for the table.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My Application")
width = 1000
height = 500

def browseFile():
    global workbook, copyWorkbook, excel_file, sheetName, worksheet, df_table

    fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = '/', title = 'New File', filetypes = (('excel file', '.xlsx'), ('excel file', '.xls'), ('all files', '*.*')))
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(fileName)
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName)
    sheetCount = workbook.nsheets

    sheetName = []
    tab = []
    for x in range(workbook.nsheets):
        tab.append(ttk.Frame(tabControl))
        sheetName = workbook.sheet_names()
        tabControl.add(tab[x], text = sheetName[x])
        df_table = excel_file.parse(sheetName[x])
        lblTable = Label(tab[x], text = df_table.to_string(index = False)).pack()

toolbar = Frame(root)
btnOpen = Button(toolbar, text = "Open", command = browseFile).pack(side = LEFT)
btnQuit = Button(toolbar, text = "Quit", command = root.quit).pack(side = RIGHT)
toolbar.pack(side = TOP, fill = X)

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabHome = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill = 'both', side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

I have tried search statements that can display the table with border, but no result found. How can I add border to the table? Is it possible to add border? If not, what other method that I can use?

Comment: Could you add your import statements to the code snippet?

Comment: @Llamax I have already added my import statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

Your problem here is that, your code puts the entire dataframe into a single `Label` widget. When I tried putting a border around this label, it appeared around the whole dataframe, rather than around each cell.

## My solution

My solution to this is to go through all of the rows and create an individual `Label` widget for each cell, giving each of these its own border. I then organised them using [`.grid()`](https://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) rather than `.pack()`. For the border, I used the settings `borderwidth=2, relief="ridge"`, but you can [choose others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39416145/10790516).

I also added a feature that sets the width of each column to its longest value to prevent the label's contents overflowing.

I did not include anything to include row and column headers, but you replacing `i.pop(0)` with `i[0]` and changing `header=none` should add this feature.

## Modified code

*I have only included the* `for` *loop in your* `browseFile()` *function as I have not made any changes to the rest of your code.*

```
for x in range(workbook.nsheets):
    tab.append(ttk.Frame(tabControl))
    sheetName = workbook.sheet_names()
    tabControl.add(tab[x], text = sheetName[x])
    df_table = excel_file.parse(sheetName[x], header=None) # header=None stops the first line of the data table being used as the column header, making it appear in the data table

    # Iterates through each row, creating a Label widget for each cell on that row.
    for i in df_table.itertuples(): 
        i=list(i) # Converts the row to a more helpful list format
        row = i.pop(0) # pop returns value at position, then removes it, as we don't wan't first value of tuple (row number) in spreadsheet
        for j in range(len(i)):
            # Next two lines get the current column in a list format and convert all items to a string, in order to determine the longest item to make all label widgets the correct width.
            current_column = list(df_table.iloc[:, j])
            for k in range(len(current_column)): current_column[k] = str(current_column[k])
            # Makes label widget
            lbl = Label(tab[x], text = i[j], borderwidth=2, relief="ridge", width=len(max(current_column, key=len)), justify=LEFT).grid(row=row, column=j+1)
```

*PS: I really enjoyed solving this question. Thanks for asking!*

Comment: What if in the excel file, I have multiple sheets in it? I have tried and it only create its own border for the last sheet in the excel file as the dataframe ```df_table``` hold value for the last sheet only

Comment: I got it already! My bad I put the second ```for``` loop in a new line. Thanks for your help! You're awesome!